# Java String Parsing Error

Tags: java, string, parsing, double

Hey can someone help me with my error i am getting. I am taking apart lines out of my file and check wether they are low med or high. If the string is blank i want to read the next line in the file.  I think the error is when i am parsing the sting to a double. Heres my code any help is appriciated!
  First here is my error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at BSCQueryManager.displayBar(BSCQueryManager.java:431)
    at BSCQueryManager.main(BSCQueryManager.java:57)
```

Here is my code

```
String vMag;
            String data;
            double v;
            int highCount = 0;
            int medCount = 0;
            int lowCount = 0;
            // read file
            File inFile = new File("bsc.dat");   
            Scanner starFile = new Scanner(inFile);
            // while there is a vmag
            while(starFile.hasNext()){
                // read next line
                data = starFile.nextLine();
                data = data.substring(102, 107);
                data.trim();
            // if no vmag read next line
                if(data.trim()!= ""){
                    v = Double.parseDouble(data);
                    // if vmag is > 6.0 add to countHigh
                    if (v > 6){
                        highCount++;
                    }
                    // if vmag is 5-6 add to countMed
                    if (v >= 5 && v <= 6){
                        medCount++;
                    }
                    // if vmag is < 5 add to countLow
                    if (v < 5){
                        lowCount++;
                    }
                // end if
                }
            // end while
            }

            // display label
            System.out.println(label);
            System.out.println(highCount);
            System.out.println(lowCount);
            System.out.println(medCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
data.trim();
// if no vmag read next line
if(data.trim()!= ""){
```

with

```
data = data.trim();
// if no vmag read next line
if(data.length > 0){
```

Comment: +1 Strings are _immutable_. `String#trim()` does not (cannot) modify the string in-place, it returns a new `String` containing the trimmed result.

Comment: @ShianneRice - I'm glad to hear it. Could you do me a favour in return and **never again** start a question with *Hey*. It brutalises the English language. Also - try to avoid *So* if you are ever tempted.

Answer (score 0):

One of the strings is empty:

```
class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double.parseDouble("");
    }
}
```

produces:

```
C:\Temp>java Test1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:992)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
        at Test1.main(Test1.java:3)
```

Answer (score -1):

The data string definitely isn't parsable to a double. It may be blank (your string not empty logic is flawed, try

```
data.isEmpty()
```

instead) or the value could be something else unparseable e.g. a letter or word.

You could try debugging, or catching the exception and printing the value of data.

```
try{
 Double.parseDouble(data);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
throw new RuntimeException(data + " is not a number");
}
```

That will let you see what's going wrong.